# extract specific text using multiple regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, extract

I have a problem using regular expressions in python 3 so I would be gladful if someone could help me. I have a text file like the one below:

```
Header A
text text
text text
Header B
text text
text text
Header C
text text
here is the end
```

what I would like to do is to have a list of the text between the headers but including the headers themselves.
I am using this regular expression:

```
 re.findall(r'(?=(Header.*?Header|Header.*?end))',data, re.DOTALL)
```

the result is here

```
['Header A\ntext text\n text text\n Header', 'Header B\ntext text\n text text\n Header', 'Header C\n text text here is the end']
```

The thing is that I get the next header in the end of the every item in the list. As you can see every header ends when we find the next header but the last header doesn't end in a specific way

Is there a way to get a list (not tuple) of every header including its own text as substrings using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Header [^\n]*[\s\S]*?(?=Header|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/21

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'Header [^\n]*[\s\S]*?(?=Header|$)')
test_str = "Header A\ntext text\ntext text\nHeader B\ntext text\ntext text\nHeader C\ntext text\nhere is the end"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Yes this is correct too!Thank you vks as i told in another comment I think i have to read regex again to understand how they work!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
re.findall(r'(?=(Header.*?)(?=Header|end))',data, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
>>> s = '''Header A
text text
text text
Header B
text text
text text
Header C
text text
here is the end'''
>>> re.findall(r'Header.*?(?=Header)|Header.*?end',s, re.DOTALL)
['Header A\ntext text\ntext text\n', 'Header B\ntext text\ntext text\n', 'Header C\ntext text\nhere is the end']
```

Include `\n` inside the positive lookahead in-order to not to get `\n` character at the last for each item.

```
>>> re.findall(r'Header.*?(?=\nHeader)|Header.*?end',s, re.DOTALL)
['Header A\ntext text\ntext text', 'Header B\ntext text\ntext text', 'Header C\ntext text\nhere is the end']
```

**OR**

Split your input according to the newline which exists just before to the string `Header`.

```
>>> re.split(r'\n(?=Header\b)', s)
['Header A\ntext text\ntext text', 'Header B\ntext text\ntext text', 'Header C\ntext text\nhere is the end']
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash!That's correct too! I think i have to read more about regex to understand how they work! Thanks a lot!